# Detect tap on image view

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app, where I have a image and I want a action to happen when I tap on the image. I have already set up much of the design, so changing the image view to a button with an image would be a lot of work.

Is there a way to constrain the button to be the same size as the image, and at the same place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the image view's `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the image view.

You can do it in a storyboard by checking the “User Interaction Enabled” checkbox, dragging a tap gesture recognizer onto the image view, and connecting the tap gesture recognizer to an action in your view controller.

[image: storyboard demo]

Comment: how do you add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the image view?

Comment: wish there was a way to give two likes for these kinds of answers, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTapImage")
    yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc private func didTapImage() {
    // Performed action on tap
}
```